# Relay contact insulation doesn't seem to be enough

Tags: led, relay, home-automation, esp32, cob

I'm working with an ESP32 and a 4 relay module. The problem seems to be that the insulation of contacts in the relay is not enough.

[image: wiring diagram]

Relays close perfectly and my lights turn on, but when they open, a 20V or less voltage remains between the main contact and the normally open contact, enough to faintly turn on my lights. As you can see, my lamp is connected to the normally open contact of the relay. I've considered adding a resistor in series with the lamp to drop the voltage, no luck so far.

The datasheet corresponding to the part number:

https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/114955/ETC1/JQC-3F.html

In my case the manufacturer is BESTEP but the part number is the same, JQC-3F-05VDC-C.

Regarding the lamp, it's 5 parallel 50 watt COB LEDs. Couldn't find the datasheet.

[image: photo of 50W COB LEDs]

This faint light is greatly undesired. Any clues as to how to work around this?

Comment: Can you add a link to the datasheet for the relay board (not a link to an Amazon / Ali-what's-it ad page) or the datasheet for the relay and the LED lamp. Otherwise we're all just guessing.

Comment: Yes, please.  I don't believe the photo in the illustration is the same as  the device you do have...

Comment: Great, thanks for your replies.

Comment: What is the physical wiring topology? Does the supply hot (brown) run alongside the switched-hot (orange) for any distance?

Comment: You could say the run along for 7cm maybe

Answer (score 6):

If the relays are wired to bring out the NC contact you can wire the pole of the relay contact to the LED, the NO to the supply live and the NC to supply neutral. In this way, when the relay resets back to not powering the LED lamp, it will also short out the lamp (but not in a way that is dangerous).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9Vk70.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It's possible that if there's several metres of wiring involved in the installation, there might be enough capacitive cross-connection between otherwise isolated conductors to drive enough reactive current to glow the LEDs.

Comment: This seems like a great idea. I'l try it out, thanks a lot

Comment: This phenomenon also happens with three-way switches commonly and modern LED lights. Because they are so sensitive that milli watts of power is enough to cause a faint glow at night.

Comment: Putting 240V across the contacts of a cheap Cheese relay with faked safety ratings. *What could possibly go wrong?*

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution. The 240V input to the unit is connected to an internal bridge rectifier, shorting the 240V wont discharge the internal capacitor.

Comment: Read the question, especially the 20 volt bit.

Comment: The 20V is 220V divided between the lamp and the voltmeter connected in series. There is no such thing as "Relay contact insulation doesn't seem to be enough". It could be that the voltmeter across the contact turns the light on a little. If the voltmeter removed the light will go dark in several seconds.

Comment: @Moty it is, if the relay is not a relay at all, but a solid-state "relay". And cheaply made; the mentioned "manufacturer" is a reseller of fell-off-a-truck-in-Shenzhen Alibaba junk. seen all over the usual digital flea market sites: Banggood, Amazon Marketplace etc.

Comment: The board in the photo uses electro-mecanical relays, no SSR and no snubbers, only a dry contact. If a contact has low resistance it burns in a second from the power dissipated on it.

Comment: I don't connect the voltimeter in series with the lamp. This 20V were measure with the lamp disconnected and the relay in the off state